# Extending a template by inherit from a base one

Tags: xml, templates, inheritance, phpldapadmin

I have an LDAP schema objectClass that extends "inetOrgPerson" by just one extra attribute (mailAlternate), which works OK in openldap. Now would like to do the same with the corresponding phpLDAPadmin's XML template, but it looks like one has to keep explicitly all the parent's attributes plus the extra one... what a waste of bits ;-)

More generically, given this *base* template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE template SYSTEM "template.dtd">

<template>
  <askcontainer>1</askcontainer>
  <description>New Base Object</description>
  <icon>address-book.png</icon>
  <invalid>0</invalid>
  <rdn>cn</rdn>
  <title>Base template</title>
  <visible>1</visible>

  <objectClasses>
    <objectClass id="baseTemplate"></objectClass>
  </objectClasses>

  <attributes>
    <attribute id="fooAttr">
      <display>Foo</display>
      <order>1</order>
      <page>1</page>
    </attribute>
  </attributes>

</template>
```

I'd like to *extend* it, kind of, with just a declaration of the *extra* attribute `barAttr`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE template SYSTEM "template.dtd">

<template>
  <askcontainer>1</askcontainer>
  <description>New Extended Object (from Base)</description>
  <icon>address-book.png</icon>
  <invalid>0</invalid>
  <rdn>cn</rdn>
  <title>Base template</title>
  <visible>1</visible>

  <objectClasses>
    <!-- the first declaration is intended as "inherit from" -->
    <objectClass id="baseTemplate"></objectClass>
    <objectClass id="extendedBaseTemplate"></objectClass>
  </objectClasses>

  <attributes>
    <attribute id="barAttr">
      <display>Bar</display>
      <order>2</order>
      <page>1</page>
    </attribute>
  </attributes>

</template>
```

That above, unless I'm missing something, doesn't work: PLA just proposes the extra `barAttr` (`fooAttr` is missing) at creation of a new object.

So, does PLA actually supports template inheritance?